# Read Java build path entries inside a Maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a project which has dependencies in its classpath (Java buildpath). Now I have converted it to maven project and compiling it using my customized Maven plugin. Following will be my POM file -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.my.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And in `my-maven-plugin`, I have overridden compile phase -

maven-plugin pom-

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

  <name>my-maven-plugin</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.9</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-archiver</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-component-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
       <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
       <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

lifecycle.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lifecycles>  
  <lifecycle>  
    <id>customLifeCycle</id>  
    <phases>  
      <phase>  
        <id>compile</id>  
        <executions>  
          <execution>  
            <goals>  
              <goal>mycompile</goal>  
            </goals>  
          </execution>  
        </executions>  
      </phase> 
    </phases>  
  </lifecycle>  
</lifecycles>
```

components.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<component-set>
  <components>
    <component>
      <role>org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.ArtifactHandler</role>
      <role-hint>ear</role-hint>
      <implementation>org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.DefaultArtifactHandler</implementation>
      <configuration>
        <type>ear</type>
        <extension>ear</extension>
        <language>java</language>
        <packaging>ear</packaging>        
      </configuration>
    </component>

   <component>
      <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping</role>
      <role-hint>ear</role-hint>
      <implementation>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping</implementation>
      <configuration>
        <phases>
          <process-resources>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:resources</process-resources>
          <compile>com.test:my-maven-plugin:mycompile</compile>
          <process-test-resources>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:testResources</process-test-resources>
          <test-compile>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:testCompile</test-compile>
          <test>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:test</test>
          <install>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:install</install>
          <deploy>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:deploy</deploy>
        </phases>
      </configuration>
    </component>
  </components>
</component-set>
```

And , overridden compile mojo -

```
 @Mojo( name = "mycompile", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE )
 public class MyCompileMojo extends AbstractMojo{

   @Parameter( defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true )
    private MavenProject project;
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    }
}
```

Now, in compile phase, I want a list of JAR files which are present in classpath. How can I get it? I have tried following - but most of them returns target folder path and classes folder path

```
List<String> list1 = project.getCompileClasspathElements();
List<String> list2 = project.getRuntimeClasspathElements();
List<String> list3 = project.getSystemClasspathElements();
List<String> list4 = project.getTestClasspathElements();
List<Dependency> list5 = project.getCompileDependencies();
Properties list6 = project.getProperties();
List<Dependency> list7 = project.getSystemDependencies();
List<Dependency> list8 = project.getRuntimeDependencies();
```

My project structure to be compiled

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The key ingredient you're missing is [`requiresDependencyResolution`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools-archives/plugin-tools-3.5/maven-plugin-annotations/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Mojo.html#requiresDependencyResolution()), which represent the set of dependencies that will be made available to the plugin. From [the Mojo API reference](http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html):

> Flags this Mojo as requiring the dependencies in the specified class path to be resolved before it can execute. [...] If the annotation is not present at all, the mojo must not make any assumptions about the artifacts associated with a Maven project.

To have access to the compile-time dependencies of the project, you can use [`ResolutionScope.COMPILE`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools-archives/plugin-tools-3.5/maven-plugin-annotations/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/ResolutionScope.html#COMPILE):

> `compile` resolution scope = `compile` + `system` + `provided` dependencies

Among others, there is also [`COMPILE_PLUS_RUNTIME`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools-archives/plugin-tools-3.5/maven-plugin-annotations/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/ResolutionScope.html#COMPILE_PLUS_RUNTIME) to have access to runtime scoped dependencies as well, or [`TEST`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools-archives/plugin-tools-3.5/maven-plugin-annotations/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/ResolutionScope.html#TEST) to add the test scoped dependencies. When this parameter is not present for the Maven plugin, no classpath elements of the Maven project will be available to it, which is the behaviour you encountered.

Therefore, if you want the Maven plugin to get hold of the list of the compile-tile JAR files which are the dependencies of the current Maven project, you can have:

```
@Mojo(name = "mycompile", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE, requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE)
public class MyCompileMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenProject project;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        try {
            List<String> list = project.getCompileClasspathElements();
            getLog().info(list.toString());
        } catch (DependencyResolutionRequiredException e) {
            throw new MojoFailureException("Couldn't resolve compile dependencies", e);
        }
    }

}
```

The method [`getCompileClasspathElements()`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getCompileClasspathElements()) returns the list of path to the JAR files of each compile-time dependencies. It will also contain the path to the `target/classes` folder of the current Maven project, because it contains the compiled main Java sources of the project. The code above would simply print this list. Similarly, you would use [`getTestClasspathElements()`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getTestClasspathElements()) together with `ResolutionScope.TEST` to have the list of test scoped dependencies, as well as compile-time dependencies.

If you only want the path to the JAR file of the dependencies, without the classes of the project itself, you can use the method [`getArtifacts()`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getArtifacts()) instead:

```
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    Set<Artifact> artifacts = project.getArtifacts();
    for (Artifact artifact : artifacts) {
        System.out.println(artifact.getFile());
    }
}
```

Note that for this to work, you need to make sure the `compile` phase (or `test-compile`) has run. The lists are lazily-populated. Running `mvn clean test` will make sure the plugin has access to the test scope dependencies if it declared a `requiresDependencyResolution` of `TEST`. Similarly, running `mvn clean compile` (along with changing the phase to `<phase>compile</phase>`) will make sure the plugin has access to the compile scope dependencies if it declared a `requiresDependencyResolution` of `COMPILE`.

---

Couple of side-notes:

- The file `lifecycle.xml` has to be located inside `src/main/resources/META-INF/maven`. Note that this file is actually completely unused in your set-up, because you did not use the new `customLifeCycle` inside your `components.xml`, and override `ear` instead;
- The file `components.xml` has to be located inside `src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus`. Note that the `<compile>com.test:my-maven-plugin:mycompile</compile>` has to match the group id and artifact id of the plugin;
- The test project needs to use the plugin like so:

  ```
  <packaging>ear</packaging> <!-- because your lifecycle mapping override ear -->
  <dependencies>
    <!-- some dependencies like maven-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ```

  Then you can run `mvn clean package` and the plugin will correctly prints the path to JAR files of `maven-core` (for example) and its dependencies.

Comment: I have tried your solution , but it still not giving me classpath entries. (here, classpath entries I am talking about are the one which are present in .classpath file of project)

Comment: @pD7 When you added `requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE`, you need to `mvn clean install` the Maven plugin, and then when you use it in another project, it'll correctly print the path to the JAR files (which are present on your disk, in your Maven local repository). Can you expand what it not working for you? Is the list incorrect or no list at all?

Comment: I have edited my question and added test project structure. You can see there is junit.jar file on its classpath (not in dependencies tag). I want that entry to come in project.getCompileClasspathElements() list.  But I only get one entry there - E:\test\target\classes

Comment: @pD7 Aah yes, as I said in my answer, if you want all dependencies, including test scoped dependencies, you have to use `ResolutionScope.TEST`.

Comment: still not able to get it.. Am I missing any configuration while creating customized plugin?

Comment: @pD7 Couple of notes. If you want test scoped dependencies, you need to use `getTestClasspathElements()`, and you need to make sure the right phases have run, I made an edit. If that still doesn't work for you, please post the Maven command you're using; this works with the commands I posted.

Comment: I have tried all things u have mentioned.. but no luck .. I am running commands like mvn clean install , mvn clean test , mvn clean compile . Do you have any working example?

Comment: @pD7 What is in this answer is a working example for me... To have test scoped dependencies: copy the Java snippet with `project.getArtifacts();`, add `requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.TEST` on your Mojo, clean install it. Then copy the `<plugin>` plugin configuration in the answer, run `mvn clean test` on your test project (not the plugin project), you get the list of dependencies printed.

Comment: I have tried everything you have mentioned.. but no luck again.. I am getting "project.getArtifacts()" list empty

Comment: @pD7 Which version of Maven are you using? Can you make something on GitHub that I can look at? If `project.getArtifacts()` returns an empty list, it means the plugin wasn't invoked at the right phase (see last paragraph of answer).

Comment: @pD7 Wow that changes everything, you have a custom lifecycle and trying to compile things within an EAR?! Please explain more what you're trying to do in the first place, this isn't at all what the initial question looked like.

Comment: I have my custom lifecycle using which I will complie and package my studio project into ear file. Now I have some classpath entries in studio project which I want at time of compiling test classes at test-compile phase and these dependencies I can not add in dependencies tag in pom.xml file. Now when I will run 'mvn clean test' , I want to read those classpath entries in my customized MyTestCompileMojo.java class (which is in my-maven-plugin).

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. Do you actually want the dependencies that are declared _in the plugin_ and not in the test project using the plugin?

Comment: I want classpath entries of test project in plugins code.. i.e junit jar of test project

Comment: But your test project shown in the question does not have this JAR?

Comment: @pD7 I made another edit with a couple of side-notes with regard to file positioning on disk, but I still cannot reproduce any issue with what I have in this answer, considering all files from the question.

Comment: Yes I can read the jar entries which are in dependencies tag.. My question was different.. I want to read jar entries which are on classpath and not in pom.xml. (I know in case of maven project its irrelevant but its a usecase I want to follow).

Comment: @pD7 I don't understand, the classpath are dependencies written in the POM. Which classpath are you talking about? If there are no dependencies in the POM, there are no dependencies in the test classpath, compile classpath, or anything.

Comment: I have mentioned in question.. consider a normal java project.. we give dependencies in build path/classpath file .. so those dependencies I was talking about. You can see junit.jar above.. i.e. <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/junit.jar"/>

Comment: @Disha In a Maven project, you do not add dependencies manually through an IDE, Maven will not read your IDE. Dependencies are _always_ added in the POM. Otherwise, you cannot even compile your project as a normal Maven project.

Comment: yes ofcourse.. it is irrelevant. I though to try a luck if there is any way to read those jars as we can read in studion project. Thanks for all valuable information though.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

I found it here https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/

```
package com.mkyong.io;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class App{

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

        for(URL url: urls){
            System.out.println(url.getFile());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives me current projects classpath. But I want one projects classpath into another project

Comment: @Disha what about .getContextClassLoader() ??

Answer (score 0):

In completion to the previous answer, you can read all Class-Path like that :

```
public static List<String> getClassPaths() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Enumeration res;
    try {
        res = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources(JarFile.MANIFEST_NAME);
        while (res.hasMoreElements()) {
            try {
                URL url = (URL)res.nextElement();
                InputStream is = url.openStream();
                if (is != null) {
                    Manifest manifest = new Manifest(is);
                    Attributes mainAttribs = manifest.getMainAttributes();
                    String classpath = mainAttribs.getValue("Class-Path");
                    if (classpath != null)
                        list.add(classpath);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // Silently ignore wrong manifests or stop the compilation
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    // Silently ignore wrong manifests or stop the compilation
    }
    return list;
}
```

If you need to go deeper into dependencies:

```
public static List<String> getClassPaths() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Enumeration res;
    try {
        res = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources(JarFile.MANIFEST_NAME);
        while (res.hasMoreElements()) {
            try {
                URL url = (URL)res.nextElement();
                InputStream is = url.openStream();
                if (is != null) {
                    Manifest manifest = new Manifest(is);
                    Attributes mainAttribs = manifest.getMainAttributes();
                    String classpath = mainAttribs.getValue("Class-Path");
                    if (classpath != null)
                        for (String lib : classpath.split(" ")) {
                            try {
                                list.addAll(getClassPathsFromJar(lib));
                            } catch (IOException ioe)
                            {
                                list.add(lib);
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // Silently ignore wrong manifests or stop the compilation
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    // Silently ignore wrong manifests or stop the compilation
    }
    return list;
}

public static List<String> getClassPathsFromJar(String lib) throws IOException {
    List<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();
    JarFile jar = new JarFile(lib);
    Manifest manifest = jar.getManifest();
    if (manifest == null) {
        entries.add(lib);
        return entries;
    }
    Attributes mainAttribs = manifest.getMainAttributes();
    String classpath = mainAttribs.getValue("Class-Path");
    if (classpath == null) {
        entries.add(lib);
        return entries;
    }
    for (String l : classpath.split(" ")) {
        entries.addAll(getClassPathsFromJar(l));
    }
    return entries;
}
```

Comment: I hv tried this solution also.. but it does not give classpath entries . It only gives jar file entries which are present in dependencies tag